# how to use Jquery :focus selector on input elements in iOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, input, focus

I'm using Jquery 1.7.1 and iPad1 iOS3.

I need to fire a function on scrollstart unless an input element has focus. The function below worked for a long time, but all of a sudden it doesn't (looking aroud I guess because of switching to Jquery 1.7.1)

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
   if ( !$("input:focus").length > 0 ) {  
       self.hideAllPanels();
       }
  });
```

Specifically **$('input:focus').length = 0**, although I can detect the focus event triggering before the scroll event.

I have been fiddling with a workaround using:

```
 if ( !$(document.activeElement).get(0).tagName == "input" ){
 ....
 }
```

But I'm not sure when the activeElement is changing, because it seems to persist for quite a while even after I'm "leaving" the resprective element.

**Question**:
Any idea why I can't detect the focus-ed element on iOS? Some hints how I could set this up with activeElement, so on blur, I'm no longer having the input as activeElement are also welcome!

Thanks for help!

Comment: Could it be because `!` has a higher operator precedence than `>` ? For instance, will this work: `if(!($("input:focus").length > 0))`

Comment: @AlexW: although I'm not sure what you mean, I think I understand.... :-)  "! beats >" correct? Never thought about that. Let me try.

Comment: You are correct. Just like precedence in mathematics, all Javascript operators have precedence, which can be overridden using parentheses. In the answer below, the function is evaluated before the `!` operator so it is no longer a problem of `!` vs `>`.

Comment: Ah... mathematics.... thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
   if (!$("input").is(':focus')) {  
       self.hideAllPanels();
   }
});
```

This seems to work for me, but it will fire the function multiple times during scroll if an input element does not have focus.

Comment: I guess I'm ok with multiple fires during scroll. It's just that on iPad the keyboard jumping up when tapping on an input fires a scroll event, which fires my hide-routine unless I catch the input I'm focussing on.